# Jenkins Firefox interface not rendering properly

Tags: firefox, selenium-webdriver, jenkins, java-7, xvfb

I'm using dockerized jenkins and run Firefox headless with Xvfb. But when running the test modules they are not rendering properly. Bamboo run the same test case finely. all the environment factors are same.

can anyone suggest me a way to get rid of this.
Jenkins Version : 1.580.3
JDK : 1.7.0_79
firefox : 25.0

Can Xvfb course a rendering issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the problem. I'm posting this for any one who is interesting in this matter. All i had to do was changing the resolution of the Xvfb using the advance options. when I increased the resolution, it worked perfectly for me.